# meteor template .not :not css selector compound

Tags: css, meteor

cant seem to find the right pattern to do a meteor compound css selector. Looking to do the equivalent of this is meteor

```
#link:not(.disabled)
```

Comment: just use normal selector, #link { .. some styles } #link.disabled { ... another style... }

Comment: @max i need not clss selector

Comment: can you post a sample of the element that this css rule should apply to, so we can help verify if your css is correct?

Comment: nothing more than a standard anchor link:
<a id="link" class="disabled" href="#">reset</a>